# Redis using members of sorted list to delete external keys

Tags: redis, jedis

Using sort one can sort a set and get external keys using results from the sort component of query.

By way of example:

- If the external key/value are defined as various keys using the pattern:`itemkey:<somestring>`
- And a sorted list has list of the  members then issuing command `sort <lists key> by nosort get itemkey:*` would get the values of the referenced keys.

I would like to be able to sort through a sorted list and delete these individual keys but it appears that `sort <key> by nosort del itemkey:*` is not supported.

Any suggestions on how to get list of values stored in a set and then delete the external keys?

Obviously I can do this with two commands, first getting the list of values and then by iterating through list call the delete function - but this is not desirable as I requite atomic operation.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure atomic operation one can use either transactions or redis' lua scripts. For efficiency I decided to go with using script. This way the entire script is completed before next redis action/request is processed.

In code snippet below. I used `loadScript` in order to store script redis side reducing traffic with every call, the response from `loadScript` is then used as identifier to Jedis's `evalsha` command.

Using Scala (Note Jedis is a Java library, hence the `.asJava`):

```
val scriptClearIndexRecipe = """local names = redis.call('SORT', KEYS[1]);
   | for i, k in ipairs(names) do
   |   redis.call('DEL', "index:recipe:"..k)
   | end;
   | redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1]);
   | return 0;""".stripMargin

def loadScript(script: String): String = client.scriptLoad(script)

def eval(luaSHA: String, keys: List[String], args: List[String]): AnyRef = {
  client.evalsha(luaSHA, keys.asJava, args.asJava)
}
```